# Subdomain loading main root directory instead of subdomain root directory

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I have a website and am trying to create a subdomain. However, the subdomain is loading the root directory of example.com, instead of loading the root directory of sub.example.com. Here are my Nginx configuration files:

Subdomain configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name sub.example.com;
}

server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332   #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/sub/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri.html $uri.php $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

Main domain configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {

    # SSL configuration

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|woff|woff2)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }
    location ~*  \.(pdf)$ {
        expires 30d;
    }
    #  Ensure requests for pagespeed optimized resources go to the pagespeed
    #  handler and no extraneous headers get set.
    location ~ "\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+" { add_header "" ""; }
    location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_static/" { }
    location ~ "^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon" { }
}
```

I know that it is not getting the correct root domain because if I visit, for example, example.com/testpage.html, I can type sub.example.com/testpage.html and it loads the exact same thing, for any page I try.

Also, visiting sub.example.com redirects to example.com.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Two of your `server` blocks are missing a `server_name` directive. Test the configuration using `nginx -T`

Comment: Thanks, Richard but I don't think this would work. We separate the server blocks for SSL purposes. See [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-3-configure-tlsssl-on-web-server-(nginx)).

Comment: I think it's just running your default servers. Your current configuration is flawed because you have two server blocks listening on port 443 with no name, or the subdomain is not being read at all. The only way to check is to use `nginx -T` and look for errors and warnings.

Comment: Agreed with @RichardSmith. Your subdomain config needs a server_name. SNI will take care of SSL stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as @Richard Smith and @EEAA said, it is simply a case of not having separate server blocks.

To fix the error, I:

- Combined the two server blocks in each file
- Removed the line 'return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;' because it was causing a redirect loop.

Thanks, @Richard Smith and @EEAA!

Comment: You might also want to add a `root` directive to your port 80 listener for sub.example.com. It's currently rooted at the default nginx root .